# Is Mark Watney really a space pirate?

Tags: international, law-of-the-sea, space

In the movie/book *The Martian* there's a NASA astronaut on the Mars named Mark Watney.
He's arguing that the surface of the planet is juridically considered sea.

Because he takes control of another (empty) space ship without explicit permission, he considers himself a space pirate.

1. Is that reasoning correct?
2. Does the law of the sea really apply to other planets?

Comment: No, it does not. See [this answer](http://law.stackexchange.com/a/658/333) to the question [Under which law the person who commits a crime on the moon gets prosecuted?](http://law.stackexchange.com/questions/657/under-which-law-the-person-who-commits-a-crime-on-the-moon-gets-prosecuted) for more information.